# Replace anything up to a word, not a character, using 'sed'

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I know how to use `sed` with the `[^xxxx]` syntax to exclude characters, but how do I exclude a word?  For example my variable:

```bash
var="
Now is the time
for all good men 
to come 
to the aid  
of the party"
```

Now:

```bash
echo $var | sed ...
```

... and I want to end up with:

```
REPLACED time
for all good men 
to come 
REPLACED aid  
REPLACED party
```

... this should be simple but I can't figure out how to do it.

```bash
echo $var | sed -r 's/^[^the]*the/REPLACED/'
```

... is sorta close, but the `t` `h` `e` are matched as individual characters, not as the word `the`.

If there are solutions where I can replace everything up to the first of multiple occurences, or even up to a specific occurence, that would be even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s/.*the/REPLACED/` replaces everything up to the rightmost occurrence of `the` because that `.*` is greedy and wants to match as much as possible.

`.*` is 0 or more (`*`) characters (`.`) *as many as possible* and will happily gobble up all occurrences of `the` not including the last one which needs to be matched by the following `the` part of the regexp.

Almost 30 years ago, `perl` 5 introduced a variant of `*`: `*?`, which also matches 0 or more of the preceding thing but *as few as possible*:

```
printf '%s\n' "$var" | perl -pe 's/.*?the/REPLACED/'
```

Few `sed`s have added support for those new `perl` operators. I know of only two implementations (`ssed` with `-R`, and ast-open's with `-E`/`-A`/`-X`/`-P`). In other `sed`s, `?` matches a literal `?` or with `-E`/`-r`, `*?` is either an error or is the same as `*` as it's understood as the `*` operator (0 or more) combined with `?` (0 or 1).

With `sed` implementations that don't support `*?`, when the thing to  replace is a single character like `x`, you use `s/[^x]*x/REPLACE/` to say 0 or more (`*`) characters other than `x` (`[^x]`), as many as possible, and because we exclude `x`, that will store before the first `x` occurrence.

You can't use that for strings of more than one character, as you can't say 0 or more characters as many as possible *as long as that doesn't include "the"*. So you need a different approach.

`s/the/REPLACEMENT/` replaces the first occurrence of `the`, so the common approach in standard `sed` to replace everything up to the first occurrence of a string of characters, is to replace it with a newline (that character is guaranteed not to occur in the pattern space otherwise), and then replace everything up to that newline:

```
sed 's/the/\
/;s/.*\n//'
```

Comment: Sheesh it's just that simple!  I thought you always had to use an exclusion to indicate where the '.*' part of a search ended. Seems '.*the' means: anything EXCEPT 'the' and then 'the' itself.  All this time I've been making it far more difficult than it is.

Comment: @RayAndrews Oh, careful about the "EXCEPT" part! If you have normal regular expressions, they are greedy, so `.*the` will match the _longest_ sub-string that ends in a `the`, which will also swallow any occurences of `the` that come before the last one. Only with the `perl`-specific non-greedy `*?`-operator will the match stop at the _first_ occurence of `the`.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve that as follows, *assuming that there is at most one instance of `the` on the line*:

```
 sed -E 's/.*\Wthe(\W.*)/REPLACED\1/'
```

This will replace everything up to the last occurence (remember, RegExes are greedy) of `the` with your replacement text.

- It does so by storing everything after the last occurence `the`, enclosed by non-word characters (to prevent partial word matches such as `theoretical`), including the non-word character ending the `the`, in a capture group `( ... )`.
- It will then replace the line by the replacement text, followed by the content of the capture group (which is referred to as `\1` because it is the first such group in the search pattern). This somewhat involved method is necessary so that the character terminating the `the` is also transferred over to the replacement text.

---

If you want to replace everything up to the *first* occurence, you may have to resort to `awk`:

```
awk '(i=match($0,/\Wthe\W/)){print "REPLACED" substr($0,i+4);next} 1'
```

This will check if the string `the`, surrounded by non-word characters, occurs on the line, and store the position in a variable `i`.

- If `i` is non-zero, it will print the replacement text and the substring of the current input line starting *after* the occurence of `the`, but otherwise skip execution to the next line.
- If `i` is zero, it simply prints the current line as-is.

Comment: Do you mean 'up to the last occurrence'?  That seems to be how it's working.  But it does work!  Where can I read up on ' \W ' and similar things like ' \b '?

Comment: @RayAndrews Glad to hear it works :) As to your question: It _replaces_ everything _up to_ the last occurence of `the`, but it does so by _placing_ everything _after_ that occurence into the capture group, and setting the replacement text to `REPLACED` plus the content of the capture group. Perhaps I need to work on the phrasing to make it clearer ...

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to replace everything to the first `the` you may need non-greedy quantifiers, and those aren't recognized by neither Basic Regular Expression, nor Extended Regular Expression.

In that case if `sed` isn't mandatory for you, you could use `perl`:

```bash
perl -pe 's/.*?\Wthe/REPLACED/'
```

And if you need to replace up to `n` occurrence (replace `n` by your number of occurrence) :

```bash
perl -pe 's/(.*?\Wthe){1,n}/REPLACED/'
```

Comment: When I got involved in Linux I sorta had to decide on sed or awk or perl and I'm not sure I did the right thing going with sed -- it seems awk and perl are more powerful.  Which one should I learn?  They say there is NOTHING you can't do with perl.

Comment: @RayAndrews this is a tricky questions in my opinion. It depends a lot on what you are trying to achieve. And anyone would need more than 500 character to answer. Asking a new question may be your best shot to get a full answer

Comment: They don't like that kind of question tho.  It is rather subjective and I'd like your subjective opinion :)